# Change slide-toggle text on toggle change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a basic slide-toggle in my app.
I want to change the text of the slide-toggle based on the if the toggle is toggled or not. Basically display different text when the button is toggled.

I tried using toggleChange() method of slide-toggle but I'm unable to show that text when I reload.
Also since the function is called on toggle change, it displays text even when toggle goes to the off state as the toggle event is triggered. 
I want to change the text when the button is toggled but only save the toggled text when the save setting button is clicked.I think I'll have to use session or local storage to store the text message

I can't seem to figure out what to do now.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my ts code

```
export class PolicyComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  policy3: boolean=false;
  policy4: boolean=false;
  message:string="Message1";
  test:boolean=false;

  disable:boolean=true;
serverData:any
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private policyService:PolicyService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {


  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      Policy1: new FormControl(false, []),
      Policy2: new FormControl(false, [])
  });
  this.policyService.getPolicy().subscribe((response) => {
      this.serverData = response[0];
      if(this.serverData.policy1=="F")
      {
        this.policy3=false;
      }
      else this.policy3=true;

      if(this.serverData.policy2=="F")
      {
        this.policy4=false;
      }
      else this.policy4=true;


      this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.setValue(this.policy3);
      this.formGroup.controls.Policy2.setValue(this.policy4);
  });
  // if(this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value)
  // {
  //   this.message="Message1";
  // }
  // else if(!this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value){
  //   this.message="Message2";

  // }
   // this.policyService.getUserById(+ localStorage.getItem("policyId")).subscribe();
}

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log("Policy1::"+this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value);
    if(this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value)
    {
      this.serverData.policy1="T";
    }
    else{
      this.serverData.policy1="F";
    }


    console.log("Policy2::"+this.formGroup.controls.Policy2.value);
    if(this.formGroup.controls.Policy2.value)
    {
      this.serverData.policy2="T";
    }
    else{
      this.serverData.policy2="F";
    }
    //this.policyService.updatePolicy(this.policy.id,{policy1:this.policy.policy1}).subscribe(err=>{console.log(err)});
    this.policyService.updateUser(this.serverData).subscribe(err=>{console.log(err)});
 //   alert(JSON.stringify(formValue, null, 2));
 this.disable=true;

  }

  onChange(ob: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    // this.policy3 = !this.policy3;
    this.disable=false;
  }

  onChange1(ob: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    // this.policy4 = !this.policy4;
    this.message="Slide";
    this.disable=false;
  }
  displayMessage()
  { console.log("Value is:"+this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value);

    if(!this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value)
    {
      this.message="Message1";
    }
    else if(this.formGroup.controls.Policy1.value){
      this.message="Message2";

    }

   }
}
```

Here is my template code:

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()" ngNativeValidate>
  <mat-action-list>
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle       
      (change)="onChange($event)"  (toggleChange)="displayMessage()"  formControlName="Policy1" >{{message}}</mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item> 
    <mat-list-item > <mat-slide-toggle  (change)="onChange($event)"  formControlName="Policy2">Policy2</mat-slide-toggle></mat-list-item>

  </mat-action-list>
  <p>Form Group Status: {{ formGroup.status}}</p>

  <button mat-rasied-button [disabled]="disable" type="submit">Save Settings</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Revise your question to be more specific regarding what you want to accomplish. if `it displays text even when toggle goes to the off state as the toggle event is triggered` is not an issue you are trying to resolve, and you only want to know how to display text after screen refresh, please remove it from your question.

Comment: Hi ,I've modified the question

Answer (score 6):

and another solution

```
<mat-slide-toggle #slide formControlName="enabled">
     <span>{{slide.checked?'label 1':'label 2'}}</span>
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please note the following about `toggleChange`, this is the reason they also have a `dragChange` event.

> The event does not fire when the user drags to change the slide toggle
>   value.

My personal preference would be to use `(change)` in this scenario, and evaluate the event to see if `e.checked` is `true` or `false`... this approach, it wouldn't matter if the toggle was a drag event or not, your method would be called on any change and only set the message if the toggle is in a `checked` state.

```
<mat-slide-toggle       
      (change)="onChange($event);displayMessage($event)"
        formControlName="Policy1" >{{message}}</mat-slide-toggle>
</mat-list-item>

 displayMessage(e){
    if(e.checked)
      this.message = 'toggled'
    else
      this.message = 'Slide me!'
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9w2p8?embed=1&file=app/slide-toggle-overview-example.ts

Comment: The text is being toggled,but it disappears when I refresh the page.I want the text to be there always.

Answer (score 0):

This is nice and simple. the key is setting an id on the control itself, so that you can get a reference to its state.

```
<mat-slide-toggle class="ml-3" formControlName="paid" #paid >
   <small *ngIf="paid.checked;else notSelected" >Paid</small>
   <ng-template #notSelected>
          <small>Click to set as paid</small>
   </ng-template>
</mat-slide-toggle>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this snippet:

```
<mat-slide-toggle formControlName="Policy1">
  <span *ngIf="!Policy1.value">Message false</span>
  <span *ngIf="Policy1.value">Message true</span>
</mat-slide-toggle>
```